# SQL Server - Varchar to Decimal with reduced precision

Tags: sql-server, decimal, type-conversion

I'm currently converting a few columns in a table from varchar to decimal.  All of the values (when not null) are valid numbers.  The problem I'm having is that the desired precision for the decimal value is less than what the varchar is showing.  For instance, we're moving to decimal(5,2) on one of the columns and a value for that column in one of the rows is '259.19999999999999'.

When I try a straight CAST or CONVERT I end up getting the "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric." error.

Any easy way to do this without having to mess with CLR?

Comment: How are you converting the data?, because this: `DECLARE @A VARCHAR(30) = '259.19999999999999'
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2),@A)` works fine for me

Comment: I'll guess you also have a collation where `.` is the thousand separator and ',' the decimal. Use [PARSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) instead of convert and specify `us_english` as the culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Sorry.  Forgot to mention.  I'm on SQL2008.

Comment: Then try adding `COLLATE YOUR_COLLATION ` after your cast or convert, as shown in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  Nevermind.  One of the rows in my column was missing the decimal point in the string data.